# HttpClient.GetStreamAsync leaves connection half closed

Tags: .net, tcp, stream, httpclient, server-sent-events

I'm trying to use System.Net.Http.HttpClient to write a .NET SSE client. Everything is working, but if the server tries the close the connection by sending the TCP FIN, the client ACKs it, but doesn't respond with a FIN of its own. In my .NET code, from this point on, the call to read the stream returns immediately having read 0 bytes. It doesn't throw an exception to indicate that the connection is closed as I expect.

[image]

If I restart the web server, then the client behaves as I expect, throwing an exception to indicate that the connection was closed. In this case, I see both the server and the client send the FIN.

[image]

Am I using the client incorrectly? Is this a bug in HttpClient?

```
var stream = await this.HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(this.Url);
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
    var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize, cancellationToken);
}
```